# Output private DHCP IPs in a specific terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If I have 10 terraform modules (lets assume they're just called module01 - module10) and each module creates 10 aws instances using standard terraform code and obtains: DNS (moduleNN.example.com), a public IP (DHCP) and a private IP (DHCP in the range of 192.168.0.0/24). This would create 100 servers in total, all modules would have a different purpose but would use the same resource for their creation.

Is it possible to output all the private IP's from module01 and drop them into a file? This sounds like an easy task, but so far I've come up with nothing usable. This is used for clustering purposes (module01 is a DB cluster). The only other requirement is that the count defined in the module can be changed (e.g module01 might create 100 servers next run).

Answer (score 0):

We've got a similar problem :/ What we ended up doing was using DNS for lookups specific to our module, this would however only retrieve public IP's which may not be suitable in your case. You could output the IP's to a bucket in S3 for later use?